# PostgreSQL: How to handle COPY command output in a query?

Tags: postgresql, copy, output

What I'd like to do is handle and evaluate COPY command output in a inline query.
From standard docs ([PostgreSQL COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html))

> On successful completion, a COPY command returns a command tag of the form
> COPY count
> The count is the number of rows copied.

That's exactly what I've seen from my tests

[image: See image]

However I can't find a way to evaluate that return value `COPY 1` in a query.
For example, in a simple AND/OR condition or a CASE .
Something like that:

```
Select foo from bar where foo=2 and 'COPY 1' = (COPY (SELECT 'export data') TO '/tmp/testexport')
```

This raises an:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
> LINE 1: ...ct foo from bar where foo=2 and 'COPY 1' = (COPY (SELECT 'ex...

Any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PL/pgSQL in a `DO` statement:

```
DO
$$DECLARE n bigint;
BEGIN
   COPY uni TO '/dev/null';
   GET DIAGNOSTICS n = ROW_COUNT;
   RAISE NOTICE '%', n;  -- or do something else with it
END;$$;
```